# Remove extra line endings when reading from stdout in Node?

Tags: node.js

```
const process = spawn(...);
process.stdout.setEncoding("utf8");
process.stdout.on("data", (data) => { console.log(data) }
```

produces

```
{
  data: 'Result__<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\r\n' +
    '<?tgml 2.0?>\r\r\n' +
    '\r\r\n' +
    '<Tgml Height="400" Stretch="Uniform" Width="600">\r\r\n' +
    '  <Layer Stroke="None" Fill="#000000" Name="basic-shapes">\r\r\n' +
    '    <Group Id="main">\r\r\n' +
    '      <Line Stroke="#0000CC" StrokeWidth="5" X1="10" Y1="10" X2="100" Y2="200"/>\r\r\n' +
    ...
}
```

It seems like each line gets an extra line ending.

What is a reliable to remove only the extra line endings added from reading, and not any line endings that exist in the original document?

Answer (score 0):

Explanations in the comments of the snippet:

```js
var data = 'Result__<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\r\n' +
    '<?tgml 2.0?>\r\r\n' +
    '\r\r\n' +
    '<Tgml Height="400" Stretch="Uniform" Width="600">\r\r\n' +
    '  <Layer Stroke="None" Fill="#000000" Name="basic-shapes">\r\r\n' +
    '    <Group Id="main">\r\r\n' +
    '      <Line Stroke="#0000CC" StrokeWidth="5" X1="10" Y1="10" X2="100" Y2="200"/>\r\r\n';

var prevIndex = 0;
var newData = "";
while(prevIndex != -1){ // until no new lines found.
  nextN = data.indexOf('\n',prevIndex); // Find the index of the next new-lien in string
  while(data[nextN]=='\n') nextN++; // Pass over adj. new lines
  newData += data.slice(prevIndex,nextN-1); // copy the from the last index until current location, removing one '\n'
  prevIndex = nextN; // hold current index for the next trim.
}

console.log(newData); // this is the new string.
```